# Possible to include a Word document in a WSP

Tags: 2010

... and put it into a Library on Feature Activated?  I have a library that I am creating on Feature Activated and I would like to insert a document into it after I create it.

Where in my Visual Studio project should I include my document and how would I reference it's location when I go to insert it into the Library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use modules to add files. here is a good [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231567.aspx) from ms